# Integer wraps around?

Tags: c++, casting, queue, arrays, void-pointers

I'm trying to store some integers in a queue, which queue is basically a fixed size char array storing integers (or every value) byte by byte:

```
class fixed_size_queue{
    char *buffer;
    unsigned int head;
    int tail;
    q_typeinfo   tinfo;
public:
    fixed_size_queue(q_typeinfo tinfo_):tinfo(tinfo_) { 
    buffer = new char[MAX_SIZE*tinfo.get_size()];
    head = 0;
    tail = -1;
    }
    char* pop() {
    char* value = buffer+head;
    head++;
    return value;
    }
    void push(char* value) {
    tail++;
    buffer[tail] = *value;
    cout<<"pushing value = "<<(int)*value<<endl; //line 22
    }
};
```

When trying to push values to this queue, I use:

```
void push_q(void* value){
    q.push(value);
}
```

With the above, if I push values from 0 to 127, they are pushed and popped correctly. If I push value 128, at line 22, it outputs "pushing value -128". Pushing 129 outputs -127 and goes on until it reaches 127 again and wraps around.

The size for each integer is 8 in the queue's array (I'm rounding it up due to some reasons) but I've tried with 4 and the same strange error appears.

I have also tried using reinterpret_cast, to cast and copy "value" to a char* when pushing or popping the values but the same thing happens. Does anyone find something wrong?
Thank you!

--Update:
Finally, the problem was not the type. I just wanted to store the bytes of any variable. For example, an integer should be split into (4)char-bytes and be stored in the array. What was needed was a copy of the integer's data to the char array! This above, didn't work because only one byte was copied every time. Also increments of head and tail should be +=sizeof(int).

Comment: May be you can use unsigned char for your buffer? Because signed holds data from -127 to 128

Comment: `char` can be either signed or unsigned, depending on the implementation. As other pointed out, use `unsigned` version if that's the intent.

Comment: Thank you! It worked with unsigned for 128 value for pushing and popping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are seeing is the effect of storing your data in a a `char` data type - which is typically a signed value which can hold values from -127 to +127 (you would expect -128, but that is apparently the C++ spec.

Take a look at this SO question [size-of-int-long-etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589575/size-of-int-long-etc/589684#589684) and use your knowledge of your application to decide what datatype your should be using.

Comment: Technically speaking, signed overflow causes undefined behaviour, so be careful.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `unsigned char` rather than `char`, and all will be fine.

Of course, if you are actually storing values beyond 255 - or want to store negative values - you will need to do something more than what you have shown above.